How to find the inverse Laplace transform of function $s\csc(2s)$?
When dealing with one ODE, it happened to find the inverse Laplace transform of function
$$
F(s)=\frac{s}{\sin(2s)}.
$$
I suppose it exists the inverse Laplace transform, but I could not find any standard formula from Laplace tables, either. I try to expand in Laurent series and found
$$
\frac{1}{\sin(s)}={\frac {-2i{{\rm e}^{-is
}}}{{{\rm e}^{-2is}}-1}} 
$$
from here.
But it seems incredibly difficult to proceed. Would someone has a simple way, please advise?

Since $F(s)$ doesn't tend to zero as $s$ goes to infinity, its inverse Laplace transform can't be an ordinary function, but rather a distribution. And even then, it seems a bit unlikely to get infinitely many poles on the right half of the plane. Are you sure that you've done everything else up to that correctly?

@S.C., Yes, you are right. I was vaguely feeling that not easy to find an ordinary function since it can even be growing  faster than $\mathcal{L}^{-1}[s]$. I need to double check...

It is tempting to try Post's inversion formula, but not successful. If someone has this expertise please instruct. Lorem Ipsum!
